# I am able to update my label.Content, but it doesn't show the change in the window

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two classes, a server and the MainWindow : Window class. All I want to do is have my WPF show that there was a connection once I call the Data_Received() method. It's fairly straight forward, but it's not showing any changes on the GUI despite my confirmation of the variable label.Content changing.

In my Server class:

```
   public static void ClientHandler(object obj)                       // Setup a NetworkStream for the client and a MemoryStream to write to
    {

        TcpClient client = (TcpClient)obj;                              //Maps the "obj" arg to a TcpClient 
        NetworkStream netStream = client.GetStream();
        BinaryWriter binWriter = new BinaryWriter(netStream);
        OkResponse(binWriter);
        MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
        window.Data_Received("CONNECTION RECEIVED");

...
```

In my Window class

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Data_Received(string message)
    {
        label.Content = message;           
    }

}
```

I can Console.WriteLine(lable.Content); before and after updating it with "message", and it does in fact change. But on the GUI, there's no change.

Comment: You're creating a *new* MainWindow instance, where you call the Data_Received method. But you never show that window. You certainly want to call the method on the already existing window instance.

Comment: how are the two classes connected? do you have an instance of the server class in your MainWindow?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a misunderstanding of instances.

The window that you create in your server class in the method `public static void ClientHandler(object obj)` is not the same window where you expect to see the label text.

the line:

```
MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
window.Data_Received("CONNECTION RECEIVED");
```

creates a different/new instance because you use the `new` keyword.
What you need is the actual instance of your `MainWindow`!

If you have an instance of your server class inside the `MainWindow` class,
you could create an event in your server class and subscribe to it in the `MainWindow` class. Fire that event and pass the message.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, your ClientHandler method call from other thread, then main window thread. In that case you observe any bugs (begins from "unupdateble" label to exception occur). To fix it, you must attach code, than updates the label to main window thread:

```
public static void ClientHandler(object obj)
{

    TcpClient client = (TcpClient)obj;                              //Maps the "obj" arg to a TcpClient 
    NetworkStream netStream = client.GetStream();
    BinaryWriter binWriter = new BinaryWriter(netStream);
    OkResponse(binWriter);
    //MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
    //MainWindow window MUST be created and showed already 
    //and we MUST use here that instance
    window.Dispatcher.Invoke(()=> window.Data_Received("CONNECTION RECEIVED"));
```